# Create multiple lists with one command

Tags: r

I would like to create multiple empty lists with single command. For eg,

```
P1<-list()
P2<-list()
.
.
.
P100<-list()
```

Here I am forced to create each of these 100 lists manually, I want to automate the process. I am expecting 100 empty lists numbered P1 to P100.

Comment: Try `setNames(replicate(100,list(),simplify=FALSE),paste0("P",1:100))`. You shouldn't pollute your global environment with so many objects. Rather, build a named list (as my line).

Comment: Thanks @nicola your advice was most useful and relevant

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a one-line code like below?

```
for (k in seq(100)) assign(paste0("P",k),list())
```

or

```
sapply(seq(100), function(k) assign(paste0("P",k),list(),envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

Comment: `assign` should be used very rarely and only if necessary. Here it's not and the bad habit of building many objects instead of a single list should be discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

You could use :

```
n <- 10
list_vec <- setNames(vector('list', n), paste0('P', 1:n))
```

To get data in separate objects you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(list_vec, .GlobalEnv)
```

However, as @nicola commented you should keep data in the list and avoid polluting your global environment with so many objects.